# How to select or play a system sound in windows phone 7(.1)?

Tags: windows-phone-7, system-sounds

I want the user of my app to be able to select a sound from the windows phone 7 system sounds, or play a specific one (like playing the "new email"-sound).

How can I enumerate the installed sounds? Or is there a builtin sound-selector? Can I ask the system which sounds are played for what events?

Answer (score 1):

Access to system sounds is not available. This include playing the sounds or seeing what files/sounds are associated with what events.

The exception is saving new files to use as ringtones which can now (as of 7.1) be done with the [SaveRingtoneTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.saveringtonetask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

Comment: So if I want a notification sound to play I need to package one with my application?

Comment: If you want to play a specific sound then you'll need to include it. Making sure you have the permission to distribute it, etc. first of course. ;)

Comment: Yeah, thats the main problem - I would need to create my own sounds. Access to play the system sounds would be a real help :(